# New Random only returns a zero... Why is that?

Tags: c#, random

My C# Windows Form application random number generator is only returning the value of zero every time I run the app.  I have looked online and it seems that people sometimes get a number to repeat while testing but never a zero.  Which I find even odder because my parameters states the random number should be between 1 and 100...  Please Let me know what you think. Thank you!

```
int count;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random num = new Random();
    count = num.Next(1, 101);
}
```

Comment: How are you observing the value of `count`? You should probably post that code too.

Comment: wire the event to the Form. double click on form to create event. not only creating method will work as event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Next(1, 101)` will not return a zero.  I suspect that you have not registered the `Form1_Load` event, so it is not running that code at all.

Zero is simply the default value for an `int` field.

Comment: This worked great!  Thank you.  I did need to double click the form in the designer.cs and it was moved to the class file and then worked.  Thank you everyone for your help today!

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line of code to Form's constructor and it will work :

```
this.Load += Form1_Load;
```

As already been said, `Random.Next(0, 100)` returns number in range `0 - 99` so it's not why you getting this `0` all the time. It's just that your method is not invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer one more guess as to what you're doing:

```
Using System.Diagnostics;

int count;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random num = new Random();
    count = num.Next(1, 101); // remove your break point on this line
    Debug.WriteLine(count); // put your break point here
}
```